# При создании словаря в Python 2.7 TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable

Tags: python, list, python-2.x, python-2.7, словари

Хочу составить словарь из двухмерного списка, где в тексте каждое предложение в отдельном массиве.

```
counts = dict()
for line in new:
    for word in line:
        if word not in counts: 
            counts[word] = 1
        else: 
            counts[word] += 1

print counts
```

Выдает ошибку

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-57-e4f381b50f11> in <module>()
----> 1 counts = dict()
      2 for line in new:
      3     for word in line:
      4         if word not in counts:
      5             counts[word] = 1

TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
```

Comment: Вы выше перед этим кодом точно не писали `dict = ...`?

Comment: А так приведённый вами код отлично работает

Comment: вы вероятно хотите: `counts = collections.Counter(word for line in file for word in line.split())`

Comment: Вероятно где-то есть такое: dict = {}

Answer (score -1):

попробуйте заменить

```
counts = dict()
```

на

```
counts = {}
```

Comment: Это-то поможет, но реальную проблему — переопределение `dict` — не исправит